# Can domain administrators do a remote wipe for Windows Vista machines?

Tags: windows, remote-access

Can domain administrators do a remote wipe for Windows Vista machines?

Comment: Network imaging solutions pretty much satisfy this. If you can stand to put things back to an imaged state. Server 2008 has built-in tools for this or there are 3rd party solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they can. If you can connect to it, you can wipe it. It's hard, but possible.
Last week I did a remote wipe, and documented it all here:
See http://www.geeklab.info/2010/12/remote-wipe-for-windows-clients/

Answer (score 1):

No, remote wiping is currently restricted to Mobile Devices that run activesync clients and connect to an Exchange Server.

Answer (score 1):

No, remote wipe at the moment is for phones only.  Third party applications do exist - a quick Google brings up gadgettrak . com and absolute . com (no idea how good they are)

But you shouldn't need to - if you have sensitive info on a laptop you should encrypt the hard drive using BitLocker (Vista Ultimate & Enterprise only).